# Why is it that when I try and preview Einstein Bots I get connected to a Live Agent instead?

Tags: einstein

I created an Einstein Bot:
[image: bot]

And I wanted to test it out, so I used the **Preview** option:

[image: Preview]

However, the **Preview** does not connect me to a bot, but rather to a Live Agent. Here, you can see me chatting with myself (i.e. a Live Agent):

[image: Live Agent]

**My question is this: how can I make the Preview button connect me to a Bot rather than a Live Agent?**

Comment: "Are you a bot?" "No". Absolutely classic. That's exactly what a bot would say (I mean, besides honest bots). Still, hope you get an answer for this.

Comment: If you are calling an Apex Function and it fails it will automatically attempt to route to a live agent in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out: if your Salesforce Instance has access to Einstein Bots, there will be an **Einstein Bots Settings** section under the **Chat Buttons** section in **Setup**.
[image]

If you leave **Einstein Bots Configuration** blank, then (curiously enough) the preview for Einstein Bot will redirect the user to a Live Agent.

To fix this issue, simply fill in **Einstein Bots Configuration** as I have done in the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

*[@Antonio_Cucciniello](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/65079/antonio-cucciniello)'s comment solved this for me, sharing as an answer to make this more noticable.*

---

If your bot has any **Apex actions**, make sure you don't have any errors. This will automatically try transferring you to an agent.

Inside your Bot Builder's top left dropdown go to:

`Performance` ➡ `Event Logs`

Visually check the **Errors** column for any "✓" marks on any rows.

If you see any, double click the logs `Session ID`, and explore what Event's have Errors. (if it was a recent log, you might need to wait a couple minutes for the log to load its data)

To see the actual error, click the "" on the row showing the Error column with "⚠". (It's kind of confusing to click the radio input to show you the error)

When I checked, I found that my bot had error:

```
[{"message":"You don't have access to the Apex class: Bot_SearchFAQ","errorCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS"}]
```

It was easy to fix once I saw this error. ([add the permission set to my bot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_call_apex_action.htm#apex-perm-info))