# Einstein Bots preview issue

Tags: einstein, service, chat, snap-ins, bots

I can't get Einstein Bot running on my Developer org.
I followed this instructions
http://deepikamatam.blogspot.com/2018/07/einstein-bot-creation-step-by-step.html

I saw this issue

[Why is it that when I try and preview Einstein Bots I get connected to a Live Agent instead?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221477/why-is-it-that-when-i-try-and-preview-einstein-bots-i-get-connected-to-a-live-ag)

and updated configuration.

Right now I'm getting message:

```
No agents are available
Sorry that we are not able to chat with you.
Come back later or try again
```

I get it when I'm trying to get a preview and when I try to use it via snap-in on my community.

When bot is deactivated I can't see "Chat with an expert" label which means that it behavies differently.

What else I'm missing to get this working?